# Confirmation message when deleting items in the media manager

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, media-manager

I would like to have a confirmation message when I delete the items the media manager. For now, to delete an image, I just have to click on the top-right cross and the image is gone: if I make a mistake, well too bad! 
I looked into the media manager options but I couldn't see anything such as what I am looking for.

How could I get a confirmation message or a popup that will ask for a confirmation before deleting the item?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have updated the answer with instructions as to where you should add the code. I forgot that the media files are displayed using an Iframe, and loaded using the `component.php` view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a few lines of jQuery to your admin template (or add it using a plugin that fires only for the admin area):

```
jQuery("a.delete-item").on('click', function(e){
    if (confirm("Do you want to delete this image?") != true) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

That will catch the click on the delete button <kbd>X</kbd> and display a dialog box.

**Edit:**
The media files are displayed using an Iframe, which in turn is loaded using the `&tmpl=component` parameter. The code above must therefore be added to the file `administrator\templates\YOURADMINTEMPLATE\component.php` (inside a `<script>` tag).

That should work :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Lodder, but according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/click/), `.click()` is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`. What's the difference (and what's "best practice") in this case?

Comment: The `.on()` is the recommended way to do event binding as of a particular (can't remember which exactly) version of jQuery. It uses less memory and is better when for dynamic approaches. It's not of course mandatory, but definitely now the preferred method. For something as simple as the code you've written, then `click()` would be just fine, but I like to keep thing future proof just incase anything may get added to it...+1 by the way :)

Comment: Thanks @johanpw for your answer! I have added your code to administrator\templates\isis\js\template.js but it isn't doing anything. In which file of my admin template  I am supposed to add it? Thanks!

Comment: To expand on Lodder's answer,  the on() method uses delegated events.   The primary benefit being delegated events will be added to child elements not yet added to the DOM.  Using $(document).on('click', 'a.delete-item', callbackFunction); guarantees the click event will fire even on dynamically generated content not added to the DOM.  Very useful for AJAX heavy websites.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. There's always something new to learn.

Comment: You are super Johan! it's working just like what I wanted! I have added your code just below <jdoc:include type="component" /> line 50 (inside the body tag). Thanks so much!